# Perl: Why can you use @ or $ when accessing a specific element in an array?

Tags: perl

I'm a novice Perl user and have not been able to find a satisfactory answer

```
my @foo = ("foo","bar")
print "@foo[0]"
foo
print "$foo[1]"
bar
```

Not only `@foo[0]` works as expected, but `$foo[1]` outputs a string as well.

Why? This is even when `use strict` is enabled.

Comment: If you enable warnings via `use warnings;`, you will get a warning for `@foo[0]`. See http://perldoc.perl.org/perldiag.html and https://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html#Slices on "slices". `@foo[1,2,3]` is an "array slice" that returns more than one element.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Both `@foo[0]` and `$foo[1]` are legal Perl constructions.

`$foo[$n]`, or more generally `$foo[EXPR]`, is a scalar element, representing the `$n`-th (with the index starting at 0) element of the array `@foo` (or whatever `EXPR` evaluates to).

`@foo[LIST]` is an *array slice*, the set of elements of `@foo` indicated by indices in `LIST`. When `LIST` has one element, like `@foo[0]`, then `@foo[LIST]` is a list with one element.

Although `@foo[1]` is a valid expression, experience has shown that that construction is usually used inappropriately, when it would be more appropriate to say `$foo[1]`. So a warning -- not an error -- is issued when warnings are enabled and you use that construction.

`$foo[LIST]` is also a valid expression in Perl. It's just that Perl will evaluate the `LIST` in scalar context and return the element of `@foo` corresponding to that evaluation, not a list of elements.

```
@foo = ("foo","bar","baz");
$foo[0]     returns the scalar "foo"
@foo[1]     returns the list ("bar") (and issues warning)
@foo[0,2]   returns the list ("foo","baz")
$foo[0,2]   returns "baz"   ($foo[0,2] evaluates to $foo[2], and issues warning)
$foo[@foo]  returns undef   (evaluates to $foo[scalar @foo] => $foo[3])
```

---

Diversion: the only reason I could come up with to use `@foo[SCALAR]` is as an lvalue somewhere that distinguishes between scalar/list context. Consider

```
sub bar { wantarray ? (42,19) : 101 }
```

`$foo[0] = bar();` would assign the value `101` to the 1st element of `@foo`, but `@foo[0] = bar()` would assign the value `42`. But even that's not anything you couldn't accomplish by saying `($foo[0]) = bar()`, unless you're golfing.

Comment: For added confusion, `$foo{LIST}` is also valid (for a hash %foo) but does [something completely different](https://perldoc.pl/perldata#Multi-dimensional-array-emulation). Thanks, Perl 4!

Comment: @Grinnz, Re "*`$foo{LIST}` is also valid (for a hash %foo)*", No, it doesn't. `LIST` means an expression evaluated in list context, so `$foo{LIST}` doesn't describe any Perl syntax.

Comment: @ikegami I was referring to the same construct as `$foo[LIST]` above, but actually in this case it is evaluated in list context, as the list elements are joined on `$;`.

Comment: Re "*`$foo[LIST]` is also a valid expression in Perl.*", No, that's wrong. `LIST` means an arbitrary expression evaluated in **list** context (and `EXPR` means an arbitrary expression evaluated in **scalar** context), so `$foo[LIST]` incorrectly describes what Perl does.

Comment: Re "returns the list ("bar")", 1) Parens never create lists, and 2) that's just a weird way of saying "returns the scalar "bar". You're inventing non-existent concepts which only ends up causing confusion. We've seen this over and over and over again.  Similarly, `@foo[0,2]` simply returns the *scalars* "foo" and "baz".

Comment: Re "*So a warning -- not an error -- "*", A warning is a non-fatal error. I believe you mean "not an exception".

Comment: @ikegami I agree it is an incorrect interpretation to say `$foo[LIST]`, but in `$foo{LIST}` it is actually interpreted as a list. `$foo{1,2,3}` is equivalent to `$foo{join $;, 1, 2, 3}`.

Comment: @ikegami I did this, and it still acts as list context: `$; = "."; my @arr = 1..3; my %hash; $hash{@arr,5} = 1; say +(keys %hash)[0]`results in `1.2.3.5`.

Comment: @Grinnz, My apologies, there must have been an error in my test. But even though I got a detail wrong (not `$foo{EXPR, EXPR[, ...]}` but `$foo{LIST, LIST[, ...]}`), the point stands. `$foo{LIST}` is not a thing. You can see a comma is required by removing `,5` from your test.

Answer (score 7):

Perl sigils tell you how you are treating data and only loosely relate to variable type. Instead of thinking about what something *is*, think about what it is *doing*. It's verbs over nouns in Perl:

- `$` uses a single item
- `@` uses multiple items
- `%` uses pairs

The scalar variable `$foo` is a single item and uses the `$` sigil. Since there aren't multiples or pairs for a single item, the other sigils don't come into play.

The array variable `@foo` is potentially many items and the `@` refers to all of those items together. The `$foo[INDEX]` refers to a single item in the array and uses the `$` sigil. You can refer to multiple items with an array slice, such as `@foo[INDEX,INDEX2,...]` and you use the `@` for that. Your question focuses on the degenerate case of a slice of one element, `@foo[INDEX]`. That works, but it's in list context. Sometimes that behaves differently.

The hash variable `%foo` is a collection of key-value pairs. To get a single value, you use the `$` again, like `$foo{KEY}`. You can also get more than one value with a hash slice, using the `@` because it's multiple values, like `@hash{KEY1,KEY2,...}`.

And, here's a recent development: [Perl 5.20 introduces “Key/Value Slices”](https://www.effectiveperlprogramming.com/2014/07/perl-5-20-introduces-keyvalue-slices/). You can get a hash slice of either an array or a hash. `%array[INDEX1,INDEX2]` or `%hash{KEY1,KEY2}`. These return a list of key-value pairs. In the array case, the keys are the indices.

For arrays and hashes with single element access or either type of slice, you know the variable type by the indexing character: arrays use `[]` and hashes use `{}`. And, here's the other interesting wrinkle: those delimiters supply scalar or list context depending on single or (potentially) multiple items.

Answer (score 2):

Both `@foo[0]` and `$foo[1]` are legal Perl constructions.

`$foo[EXPR]` (where `EXPR` is an arbitrary expression evaluated in scalar context) returns the single element specified by the result of the expression.

`@foo[LIST]` (where `LIST` is an arbitrary expression evaluated in list context) returns every element specified by the result of the expression.

(Contrary to other posts, there's no such thing as `$foo[LIST]` in Perl. When using `$foo[...]`, the expression is always evaluated in scalar context.)

Although `@foo[1]` is a valid expression, experience has shown that that construction is usually used inappropriately, when it would be more appropriate to say `$foo[1]`. So a warning — not an excption — is issued when warnings are enabled and you use that construction.

What this means:

```
my @foo = ( "foo", "bar", "baz" );

$foo[0]        0 eval'ed in scalar cx.  Returns scalar "foo".             ok
@foo[1]        1 eval'ed in list cx.    Returns scalar "bar".             Weird. Warns.
@foo[0,2]    0,2 eval'ed in list cx.    Returns scalars "foo" and "baz".  ok
$foo[0,2]    0,2 eval'ed in scalar cx.  Returns scalar "baz".             Wrong. Warns.
$foo[@foo]  @foo eval'ed in scalar cx.  Returns undef.                    Probably wrong.
```

---

The only reason I could come up with to use `@foo[SCALAR]` is as an lvalue somewhere that distinguishes between scalar/list context. Consider

```
sub bar { wantarray ? (42,19) : 101 }
```

`$foo[0] = bar();` would assign the value `101` to the 1st element of `@foo`, but `@foo[0] = bar();` would assign the value `42`. It would be far more common to use `($foo[0]) = bar()` instead.

---

Portions of the post Copyrighted by mob under the same terms as this site.

This post addresses numerous issues in mob's [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53732305/589924), including 1) the misuse of `LIST` to mean something other than an arbitrary expression in list context, 2) pretending that parens creates lists, 3) pretending that there's a difference between return scalars and returning a list, and 4) pretending there's no such thing as a non-fatal error.

Comment: If we're going to be pedantic, this still isn't complete: the array slice `@foo[0,2]` is itself context sensitive, just like the comma operator in `$foo[0], $foo[2]`, and is implemented to act similarly to the comma operator and result in the last element of the slice in scalar context. This is notably different from `@foo` in scalar context, which returns the size. But using array slices (or list slices, which is its own special parser case) in scalar context is also pretty weird.

Comment: @Grinnz, Indeed, but since it makes no sense to use an array slice in scalar context, I'll leave the answer as-is to avoid cluttering it up. (It makes so little sense that an array slice in scalar context used return exactly the same thing as in list context for the longest time. Not surprisingly, Perl had a tendency to crash shortly after doing that.)